# initialize Manipulate with different selection

Tags: manipulate

Is it possible, and if so, how, to initialize the value of h when the value of g is changed, in the following Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[
 h = t^2;
 Grid@{{"t =", t},
   {"h =", h}}
 , {{t, 2}, {2, 3, 5, 10}}
 , Button["give h", {}]
 ]
```

At the moment, when changing the value of t, the value of h is automatically updated. I now wish to initialize the value of h to, let's say, 0, when the value of t is changed. The value of h should be updated when clicked on the `Button`, which is at this moment inactive.

What am I missing to accomplish this?

Thanks for all help, as always!

Comment: Not sure to understand but ... `Manipulate[
 Grid@{
   {"t =", t},
   {"h =", h}},
 {{t, 2}, {2, 3, 5, 10}},
 Button["give h", h = t t]]`

Comment: @belisarius: this is also going in the direction I'm looking for, but the value of h "sticks" until clicking again on the "give h" button. I wish the value of h "disappears" at the moment another value of t is chosen. Do you think this would be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
Manipulate[
 Grid@{{"t =", t}, {"h =", h}},
 {{t, 2}, SetterBar[Dynamic[t, (h = ""; t = #) &], {2, 3, 5, 10}] &},
 {{h, ""}, None},
 Button["give h", h = t^2]]
```

...unless you meant `h` to be global.

Comment: Why on Earth I keep forgetting those forms of Dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [David's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40853/1356) and on your [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40850/initialize-manipulate-with-different-selection#comment122200_40853) you can do that:

```
DynamicModule[{h, t},
 Dynamic@
  Panel@Grid[{
     {Row[{"t ", 
        Row[Button[ToString@#, {t = #; h = ""}] & /@ {2, 3, 5, 10}]}], SpanFromLeft},
     {"t=", t}, {"h=", h},
     {Button["give h", h = t^2], Button["clear h", h = ""]}}],
 Initialization :> (h = ""; t = 2;)]
```

[image]

Although `Manipulate` is not used anymore.

Comment: You can obviously make it prettier than that :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this that remains close to the original code is to use a variable to test whether `h` and `t` have changed and to only do the update when they change. You can keep everything localized by using dummy `Manipulate` variables (called `tChange` and `hChange` below).

```
Manipulate[If[UnsameQ[hChange, h], h = hChange = t^2;];
 If[UnsameQ[tChange, t], h = hChange = 0; tChange = t;];
 Grid@{{"t =", t}, {"h =", h}}, {{t, 2}, {2, 3, 5, 10}}, 
      {hChange, 0, ControlType -> None}, {tChange, 0, ControlType -> None}, 
       Button["give h", hChange = -1;]]
```

Comment: Although it does not really fit the "So when the user clicks on a different value of t, then h automatically clears out." requirement..

Comment: @Oska -- I've updated the code so that `h` returns to zero whenever `t` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to only display the value of h when the user clicks on the "give h" button, they you might consider using a second button, to clear the value of h:

```
Manipulate[
 Grid@{{"t =", t}, {"h =", h}}, {{t, 2}, {2, 3, 5, 10}}, 
 Button["give h", h = t^2],
 Button["clear h", h = ""],
 Initialization -> (h = "")]
```

[image: clear h]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm actually more looking into a way of "incorporating" the "clear h" function into the changing of the value of t. So when the user clicks on a different value of t, then h automatically clears out. After clicking of "give h", the (updated) value of h comes back. Do you think this would be possible?